Avoiding ugly errors in Manipulate (and alike functions) on start up of Notebook
When there are Cells containing Manipulate this often leads to Errors in cells right at startup.
Say I write
willReceiveValue={1,2}

in one cell and in another
Manipulate[willReceiveValue[[1]], {x, {1, 2}}]

Then upon opening the file Manipulate will show an error before ever having even run that Cell.  Is there a way to only "start" the Manipulate once its Cell gets evaluated?

This seemed to be a duplicate also to me which is why I marked it as such, but I think I was too hasty.
The other question has accepted an answer which doesn't seem to solve my problem.
Specifically, why the accepted solutions don't work: The problem is actually in the Output Cell. Shielding the Manipulate function in some way like
If[
 ValueQ[willReceiveValue],
 Manipulate[willReceiveValue[[1]], {x, {1, 2}}]
 ]

doesn't help since the input cell was never the problem. I guess I am looking to automatically remove Manipulate output cells when saving since they just don't make any sense once the data is gone.
(I would also prefer not to needlessly save data that the Notebook will anyway generate before the Input cell is run the normal way.)

I think adding the ValueQ to the definition of Manipulate itself would work since it will affect the Output Cell but this would have to happen before the Output Cell is "run". So it probably requires changing Manipulate globally on a fundamental level.

What about using SaveDefinitions -> True?

@Domen, I guess that could do. It doesn't seem the cleanest. I don't want to save the things the Manipulate depends on I just want it to not run until I have run its cell.

Maybe disable dynamic updating in the notebook?

Thanks! Yes, this is a duplicate. Don't know why I didn't find the other one. I had searched on pretty similar keywords as there are in the title.
